# Microsoft documentation for a typical Excel 365 object refers to "an object in the Applies To list", but where is the "Applies to list"?

Tags: excel, vba, code-documentation

I think my Question's title clearly expresses the essence of the information I need. I Googled `where is the "applies to list" in vba excel` and a few variations of that, all with quotes as shown, which should make Google look for that exact phrase. I also used Google Advanced Search, specifying "this exact word or phrase" to be "applies to list" (with and without quotes). No hits.

For example, [here is the last documentation that I viewed yesterday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/makecompiledfile-method):

<<

`MakeCompiledFile` method
...

Causes the current project to be written as a DLL. The DLL name is specified by the `BuildFileName` property.

Syntax
*`object`*`.MakeCompiledFile`

The *`object`* placeholder represents an object expression that evaluates to an object **in the Applies To list**... >>

... which is never shown. I've lived without seeing such a list for many years, but who knows what a person might learn from viewing one.

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation you're asking about.

Comment: IMHO, `Applies To list` not to be confused with `Applies To` which is mentioned in the bottom of many of those links, is a "list" which varies for every object. For example, an application can have an `Application` object that contains a `Document` object that contains a `Text` object. Now the `Text` object is one of the "list" of objects which fall under the `Document` object. This list is different for every *object* in different applications(*This is not restricted to Microsoft products*). I doubt you will see a comprehensive list anywhere.

Comment: Having said that, in VBA you can get a fair idea using the Object Browser (F2)

Comment: @TimWilliams:  `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/makecompiledfile-method`

Comment: I did find examples of what you were asking about, and I agree it's not very clear - if you reference a "list" then that list should be findable *somehow*...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help with the web-based docs, but if you locate the corresponding CHM file in your Office install you can see there's an "Applies To" link at the top - that will give you a list of object types or link you directly to the related object.

So I'd guess the web version was converted from the CHM (but with missing functionality).

[image]